# Parameter pack within template class constructor throws unexpected end-of-file found (C1004)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, parameter-pack

I have a template function that works okay by itself:

```cpp
// some_util_file.h
namespace ArgsUtil
{
    struct Args
    {
        void* item;
        Args* next{ nullptr };
    };

    template <typename Arg, typename... ArgRest>
    static void PackArgs(Args* args, Arg arg, ArgRest...rest)
    {
        args->item = new Arg{ arg };

        if constexpr (sizeof...(rest) > 0)
        {
            args->next = new Args{};
            PackArgs(args->next, rest...);
        }
    }
}

// main.cpp
using namespace ArgsUtil;
int main()
{
    Args* payload = new Args{};
    PackArgs<int, std::string, float>(payload, 12, "hello", -412.f);
}
```

However, when I want to write a class to utilize these two methods, I get the `unexpected end-of-file found` (C1004) error:

```cpp
// some_other_file.h

using namespace ArgsUtil;

template <typename Arg, typename... ArgRest>
class PayloadPacker
{
public:
    Args* payload{ nullptr };

    PayloadPacker(Arg arg, ArgRest...rest) : payload(new Args{})
    {
        PackArgs(payload, &arg, &rest...);
    }
};
```

For the record, if I even empty the constructor, it still gives the error. As such:

```cpp
PayloadPacker(Arg arg, ArgRest...rest) : payload(new Args{})
{ }
```

This only **doesn't** cause errors:

```cpp
PayloadPacker(Arg arg, ArgRest...rest)
{ }
```

To me, the code doesn't seem to have a dodgy part to cause problems.

I'd appreciate any hints/help and thanks in advance!

## UPDATE

I just checked the same code with a compiler outside VS 2022 and it worked fine. It has something to do with MSVC or something... I submitted an issue in the Microsoft forum but I need to find a workaround to make it compile somehow.

Comment: Do you have any `#ifdef`s in there? Are they all properly matched with `#endif`s?

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks for the response, yes I checked that and also the `;` at the end of classes they were okay